# Projection by interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm wondering what's the best way to perform a server side projection using the C# Driver 2.0. Let's consider this type

```
interface IFoo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MoreData { get; set; }
}
```

How to find all objects and return `Id` and `Name` only? Does this perform a server side projection?

```
 IMongoCollection<IFoo> collection = /*...*/
 return await collection.Find(f => true).ToListAsync<IFoo>();
```

If not, how should I create a `ProjectionDefinition` for `IFoo`?

Answer (score 2):

Since the **[`Find`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find.htm?_ga=1.156068603.1902957641.1421252340)** method returns a **[`IFindFluent`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm?_ga=1.153537528.1902957641.1421252340)** object, you could use the projection builder **[`IFindFluent.Project`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2_Project__1.htm)** method with the **[`Builders.Projection.Exclude`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/ProjectionDefinitionBuilderTests.cs)** method to exclude the `MoreData` property:

```
var q = collection.Find(f => true)
                  .Project(Builders<Foo>.Projection.Exclude(x => x.MoreData));
var results = await q.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Right, but is there a built-in way to automatically project to an C# interface? Is the `TiListAsync<T>` extension a client side cast?

Comment: @hansmaad I think you can create a new `List<IFoo>` and cast all the items when you move them over `results.Cast<IFoo>().ToList();`